# Can Naive Bayes be used with feature hashing and one hot encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, naive-bayes

I was wondering if a naive bayes implementation can be used with data that has been feature hashes and one hot encoded.  The data I am looking at is mobile ad click data from the avazu kaggle competition.  I am trying to use a script that was posted on kaggle, and use it for naive bayes instead of logistic regression.  Here is the link to the script:

https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/forum-message-attachments/58054/1753/fast_solution_v3.py?sv=2012-02-12&se=2015-09-03T17%3A56%3A11Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=4pRePuL30u3DN7JGf2%2Freio2Srz8zszkPFLv1oofbJw%3D

So my question is does feature hashing and one hot encoding work with naive bayes? If so how does it work exactly?